# not able to get values in second dropdownlist in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have got cascaded dropdown list to show items in second drop downlists regarding the selected ones in first drop downlist  for that purpose I have done like this....
code for Controller

```
namespace MvcSampleApplication.Controllers
{
    public class CascadeListController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> state = new List<SelectListItem>();
            state.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "State1", Value = "State1" });
            state.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "State2", Value = "State2" });
            ViewBag.StateName = new SelectList(state, "Value", "Text");
            return View("BasicDrop");
        }
        public JsonResult Districtlist(string Id)
        {
            var districttype = from s in CascadingDropdowns.GetDistrictList()
                               where s.StateName == Id
                               select s;            
            return Json(new SelectList(districttype.ToArray(), "StateName", "DistrictName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is for view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("State").change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/CascadeListController/Districtlist' + $('#State').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a District</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, districttype) {
                    items += "<option value = '" + districttype.Value + "'>" + districttype.Text + " </option> ";
                });
                $('#District').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>    
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.CascadingDropdowns
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BasicDrop";
}    
<h2>BasicDrop</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>DropDownlists</legend>
      @Html.Label("State")
      @Html.DropDownList("State", ViewBag.StateName as SelectList,"Select A state", new {id= "State"})         
      @Html.Label("District");       
      <div class="mycombo">
         <select id ="District" name ="Distrct"></select>
      </div>            
    </fieldset>
  </div>
}
```

when i select the item in first drop down list I am not able to see any items in second one and i have used the div property for second dropdown list for increasing the width i have specified width like '70px' but it also does not work..

Would any one pls give any suggestions on this one...
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, the cast to select list is not neccessary, you can just send the array as json. `return Json(new SelectList(districttype.ToArray(), "StateName", "DistrictName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` to `return Json(districttype.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and access the properties directly in code. `items += "<option value = '" + districttype.StateName + "'>" + districttype.DistrictName + " </option> ";`

Comment: @CharlieBrown do i need to pass any model through index  i am getting  system.InvalidOperationException

Comment: No, just use `return View()`

Answer (score 1):

Two things that are wrong in the url:

- missing slash "/" separating action name and id,
- word "Controller" should be removed from `CascadeListController`.

`$.getJSON('/CascadeList/Districtlist/'+ $('#State').val(),`

Also, it is advisable to use `Url.Content` to transform virtual server-side paths to urls:

`$.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/CascadeList/Districtlist/")'+ $('#State').val(),`

Comment: i have changed to  $.getJSON('/CascadeList/Districtlist/' + $('#State').val(),  and when i type this url http://localhost:5642/CascadeList i am getting this error System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.  would you pls help me ....

Comment: where do you type this url? Since you omitted the action name, ASP.NET uses default `Index` action. According to your code `return View("BasicDrop");`, the framework should look for "BasicDrop.aspx". Why it needs "Index" view I don't quite understand.

Comment: @Igor thanks for that but when i select the item in first dropdownlist the items are not populating in second drop down list

Comment: put a breakpoint inside `CascadeListController.Districtlist` method and see if it gets hit

Comment: hmm its not hitting that method... is there any changes need to be done in json function

Comment: @Igor still I am not able populate any details inn  second drop down list, would you pls help...

Comment: Your problem at the moment is that `CascadeListController.Districtlist` is not called. Try typing the url `[proper host]/CascadeList/Districtlist/[proper id]` directly in the browser address and see what the error is if any.

Comment: but i am not getting error i am getting this symbol "[]" ... when i type this url [proper host]/CascadeList/Districtlist/Id=1

Comment: this is not the url I suggested in my answer. what about `[proper host]/CascadeList/Districtlist/1`?

Comment: in that case also i am getting same symbol []

Comment: This means that `Districlist` method is actually getting called. You should debug it to find why it returns an empty array. Maybe you don't have any items with `StateName` equal to `1`.

Comment: Hi i have found the problem  here  $("State").change(function ()  I have missed '#' symbol before State tht i have changed later and its working ..... Any way thanks for your support.....

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("State").change(function () {
                $.getJSON('/CascadeList/Districtlist?id=' + $('#State').val(), function (data) { 
...    

        });
    });
});
```

You are missing the question-mark while passing the query-string, I think that is the mistake. Another way of achieving this is using data parameter of $.getJSON method

```
$.getJSON('/CascadeList/Districtlist', {id = $('#State').val()},
function (data) { 
    ...

});
```

I think there is one more way by directly using forward slash between url and query-string (though I am not sure, have to test it)

```
$.getJSON('/CascadeList/Districtlist/'+ $('#State').val(),
function (data) { 
    ...

});
```

EDIT: Did not observe the  "Controller" keyword in the Controller name until @Igor pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that can work for you. I have changed your code quite a bit to what I feel comfortable with and I tried to follow best practices. Edit it to fit in with your scenario. I never use `ViewBag` and I never use `SelectList`.

I will be answering this question based on my assumption that when a state is selected then all that state's districts will be loaded in a another drop down.

Go and create domain model classes called `State` and `District`. This will represent all of your states and districts.

```
public class State
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class District
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You will have a view model that you will populate with data in your controller and will then pass this view model to your view. Your view model can contain other properties if you need to capture other data.

```
public class LocationViewModel
{
     public int StateId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<State> States { get; set; }

     public int DistrictId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<District> Districts { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to populate your view model with data and pass it to the view. You will pass in a list of all your states and an empty list of districts.

```
public class CascadeListController : Controller
{
     private readonly IStateRepository stateRepository;
     private readonly IDistrictRepository districtRepository;

     public LocationController(IStateRepository stateRepository, IDistrictRepository districtRepository)
     {
          this.stateRepository = stateRepository;
          this.districtRepository = districtRepository;
     }

     public ActionResult Create()
     {
          LocationViewModel viewModel = new LocationViewModel
          {
               States = stateRepository.GetAll(),
               Districts = Enumerable.Empty<District>() // Empty because no state has been selected
          };

          return View(viewModel);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(LocationViewModel viewModel)
     {
          // Do whatever you need to do here
     }
}
```

Your view is strongly typed:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Locations.LocationViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.StateId,
     new SelectList(Model.States, "Id", "Name", Model.StateId),
     "-- Select --",
     new { id = "States" }
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StateId)

@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.DistrictId,
     new SelectList(Model.Districts, "Id", "Name", Model.DistrictId),
     "-- Select --",
     new { id = "Districts" }
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DistrictId)
```

Your jQuery to handle the change and population of the second drop down:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#Departments").change(function () {
          var url = '@Url.Action("GetDistrictsByStateId", "CascadeList")';
          var stateId = $("#States").val();

          $.getJSON(url, { stateId: stateId }, function (data) {
               $('#Districts').empty();
               var items = '<option>-- Select --</option>';

               $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                    items += "<option value='" + district.Id + "'>" + district.Name + "</option>";
               });

               $('#Districts').html(items);
          });
     });
});
```

And then lastly your GetDistrictsByStateId action method to bring back all the districts for a specific state:

```
public ActionResult GetDistrictsByStateId(int stateId)
{
     IEnumerable<District> districts = districtRepository.GetDistrictsByStateId(stateId);

     var displayedDistricts = districts.Select(x => new
     {
          Id = x.Id.ToString(),
          Name = x.Name
     });

     return Json(displayedDistricts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

There are probably other ways of doing this but this is the easiest for me to accomplish this. Please excuse if I have left something out :)

I hope this can help you on the right path.